# FPDF -> PHP - set next column width from database depend of 1st column

Tags: php, fpdf

I've an issue about FPDF to set 2nd width

I've an output like this :
[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVuVd.png)

I want to set 2nd column width same like 1st column,

but the problem is about the code, my 1st column showing with `while` like this:

```
$pro2 = new Kriteria($db);
$stmt2 = $pro2->readAll();
$stmt2x = $pro2->readAll();
$stmt2y = $pro2->readAll();
$stmt2yx = $pro2->readAll();

while ($row2x = $stmt2x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth($row2x['nama_kriteria'])+3,5,$row2x['nama_kriteria'],1,0,'L');
}

while ($row1x = $stmt1x->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Kriteria/Alternatif')+6,7,$row1x['nama_alternatif'],1,0,'L');
    $stmtrx = $pro->readR($row1x['id_alternatif']);
    while ($rowrx = $stmtrx->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth($row2x['nama_kriteria'])+3,5,$rowrx['nilai_rangking'],1,0,'L');
        //want to use this but the $row2x['nama_kriteria'] is used inside top while
        $pdf->Cell(30,7,$rowrx['nilai_rangking'],1,0,'L');
    }
    $pdf->ln();
}
```

I've no idea how to make my 2nd column width is same as 1st column,
any help would appriciate

Comment: any idea please?

Comment: help me please,, give me some idea